# how to add 0 before a number in sql row

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have a SP and a SQL table and when i insert a value 03 it is taking it as 3 like below

```
id  | state
------------
3   |   wa
4   |   ma
15  |   ak
```

Stored procedure:

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].GetCountofdata 
    (@Num varchar(10)) 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Countofdata WHERE id = @Num  
END

exec GetCountofdata '03'  --> result = 0
exec GetCountofdata '3'  --> result = 1
```

When I pass the parameter(from c#) as 03 I want result = 1
                or
Is there a way to insert value like 03 in the row(any special script while creating table)

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you just change the stored procedure to accept a number instead of text?

Comment: How do you insert the record ? Is id int data type in SQL ?

Comment: @Partha: Its VARCHAR

Comment: As far as I know int data type cant hold 03, 3 is int, 03 is not. So in case you need this, its better you store id as varchar

Comment: Then pls post code to show insert operation. Are you inserting it as 03 ?

Comment: @user190881: *Why* is it a `varchar` column, when you're clearly trying to use it as a number? As a `varchar`, "3" and "03" are very different...

Comment: @JonSkeet, OP wants '03'. OP needs result as 1 when he passes '03'.

Comment: @Partha: So if "3" and "03" are meant to be equal, that's treating them as numbers - so both the parameter and the field type should be numeric. This problem is precisely what happens when you use the wrong data type. Imagine using a query with `order by id` - you'd end up with "11" coming before "8". It's all just very, very wrong.

Comment: @Jon: i have changed to number as per your comments. Its working. Thxs

Comment: Maybe the ID field is stored as int in the database? It could also be changed to varchar(10)

Comment: @Jon: Is there a way to insert 0 to a sql row like   insert into [Countofdata] values ('09','WA'). so that the row looks like  09 | wa

Comment: Not if it's an integer field. You still seem to be in two minds as to whether this field should be a string (in which case '09' and '9' aren't equal) or an integer (in which case you can't insert '09'). You need to decide what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pad left? 
Here's a link in Sql Server: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/30469/sql-server-how-to-left-pad-a-number-with-zeros/

Answer (score 0):

In SQL (like in many other languages) to store data like  `03` and `3` you need different data types, So for `03` you would use varchar (or similar) data type that basically stores strings and treats data stored in it as string regardless of it containing numbers. When using arthimetic operations on such data, you will get something like this `03 + 03 = 0303`.

Considering your field is called `Id` i assume its used as primary key, and best practices suggest primary key fields are of int (bigint...) data type, or guid where needed, so not of string type.

So unless you actually want `03` and `3` to be different and to return different results you should change datatype of the `id` field in your table to `int`, and also change input parameter in your SP to int.

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].GetCountofdata 
    (@Num int) 
AS
...
```